# OpenID vs SAML Differences

Tags: saml

Iam just starting to pick up on Identity Federation. I have a few questions on the differences between openID and SAML. Hope to get more insights here:

Scenario:

1)What is the different between SAML and openID?

OpenID:

2) I have 3 IDP (Google, Yahoo, AOL) and 4 RP (relying parties)
   If I login to the 1st RP via a user account in Google, will I be able to SSO to the other 3 RP web site without logging in again?

3) Is openID suitable to be implemented where the RP are in the internet and the IDP is in the intranet?

SAML:

4) I read that SAML does not work well on internet and is more suitable for intranet. Is that true?

5) Is SAML suitable to be implemented where the RP are in the internet and the IDP is in the intranet?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A bit specific question. How they are stored depends on the application that uses Oauth or SAML. The safest and easiest way to handle them would be for to use some third party application or library that abstracts and takes care of the communication.

For Oauth - [look here](http://oauth.net/code/) 
For SAML  - Have a look at for example [Shiboleth](https://shibboleth.net/) or [OpenSAML](http://blog.samlsecurity.com/p/opensaml.html)